# read csv with geoJSON into pandas

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, geojson, geopandas

I am stuck on an issue. I am trying to get a file read into geopandas. The final outlook should be this one:

```
  geometry
0  MULTIPOLYGON (((30.16668 -2.42994, 30.16636 -2...
1  MULTIPOLYGON (((39.41099 8.42186, 39.41164 8.4...
2  MULTIPOLYGON (((39.36784 -4.65351, 39.36945 -4...
3  MULTIPOLYGON (((39.51667 4.13454, 39.50910 4.1...
4  MULTIPOLYGON (((39.04776 -0.00706, 39.05111 -0...
```

The csv looks like this (actual top lines below).

```
geometry,Name
"{""type"":""Polygon"",""coordinates"":[[[22.860059,10.919678],[22.930762,10.795312],[22.964355,10.751807],[23.255859,10.457812],[23.312305,10.387939],[23.456641,10.174268],[23.54502,10.030078],[23.646289,9.8229],[23.65625,9.710352],[23.642773,9.613916],[23.622656,9.340625],[23.596094,9.261914],[23.468262,9.114746],[23.462793,9.048486],[23.489063,8.993311],[23.528027,8.970605],[23.551855,8.943213],[23.537305,8.81582],[23.583203,8.76582],[23.679297,8.732471],[23.921973,8.709717],[24.048145,8.691309],[24.147363,8.665625],[24.194824,8.653369],[24.220898,8.608252],[24.17998,8.461133],[24.208398,8.369141],[24.291406,8.291406],[24.375488,8.258447],[24.456055,8.239453],[24.736719,8.191553],[24.85332,8.137549],[25.007227,7.964844],[25.200391,7.80791],[25.247363,7.724561],[25.238672,7.648975],[25.181348,7.557227],[25.190137,7.519336],[25.278906,7.42749],[25.380664,7.333398],[25.566602,7.228711],[25.888965,7.064941],[26.036523,6.955225],[26.086914,6.872119],[26.169336,6.781738],[26.28457,6.699023],[26.361816,6.635303],[26.308594,6.455322],[26.324609,6.39624],[26.35332,6.344922],[26.420508,6.27417],[26.447461,6.183008],[26.514258,6.069238],[26.593652,6.017529],[26.726367,5.998242],[26.796484,5.945508],[26.942285,5.854932],[27.083398,5.776855],[27.143945,5.722949],[27.18125,5.675146],[27.213379,5.618799],[27.229102,5.5625],[27.23252,5.440771],[27.256738,5.289648],[27.332422,5.186328],[27.40332,5.10918],[27.114941,5.197852],[27.071875,5.199756],[27.020605,5.184375],[26.870117,5.075684],[26.82207,5.062402],[26.767578,5.071924],[26.632617,5.085205],[26.173535,5.171143],[25.819922,5.253711],[25.713867,5.283691],[25.525098,5.312109],[25.400195,5.255908],[25.283105,5.062695],[25.249316,5.024561],[25.065234,4.967432],[24.978418,4.982959],[24.765527,4.930078],[24.437109,5.009961],[24.319824,4.994141],[24.227734,4.953857],[23.991699,4.86626],[23.848438,4.816357],[23.681836,4.770801],[23.523633,4.70127],[23.417188,4.663135],[23.312891,4.663525],[23.218848,4.702979],[23.115918,4.736914],[22.992871,4.743848],[22.864551,4.723877],[22.755762,4.64668],[22.711719,4.591748],[22.617188,4.445557],[22.505664,4.207666],[22.461816,4.159766],[22.449707,4.155127],[22.422168,4.134961],[21.908203,4.253906],[21.687012,4.281396],[21.537598,4.244824],[21.350195,4.311377],[21.268359,4.323096],[21.229785,4.302197],[21.125586,4.332178],[20.955762,4.413135],[20.792969,4.447314],[20.647461,4.435645],[20.558105,4.462695],[20.486523,4.541553],[20.393555,4.686182],[20.226367,4.829639],[20.002344,4.944727],[19.8625,5.031299],[19.806543,5.089307],[19.686035,5.121387],[19.500977,5.12749],[19.323438,5.070752],[19.068555,4.891406],[18.831738,4.523438],[18.699902,4.382617],[18.594141,4.34624],[18.56748,4.257568],[18.619922,4.116602],[18.633691,3.954297],[18.59668,3.678711],[18.610352,3.478418],[18.553809,3.510205],[18.499805,3.604102],[18.474414,3.622998],[18.318164,3.580811],[18.237109,3.542676],[18.193945,3.50542],[18.160938,3.499805],[18.111328,3.551074],[18.072266,3.560303],[18.010742,3.55083],[17.947949,3.551758],[17.907129,3.558398],[17.880371,3.553857],[17.806641,3.58418],[17.537695,3.661621],[17.491602,3.687305],[17.437988,3.684619],[17.298437,3.617188],[17.224707,3.598437],[17.002539,3.556689],[16.764355,3.536279],[16.67334,3.535205],[16.610742,3.505371],[16.57041,3.463086],[16.543066,3.369531],[16.496289,3.208838],[16.476758,3.165137],[16.480078,3.100977],[16.466211,2.993213],[16.45957,2.896533],[16.468555,2.831738],[16.40127,2.701025],[16.319629,2.542773],[16.251758,2.406787],[16.183398,2.270068],[16.136133,2.36377],[16.106738,2.473486],[16.095508,2.599219],[16.101855,2.632666],[16.083496,2.67002],[16.082129,2.678174],[16.059277,2.772998],[16.082422,2.839111],[16.063477,2.908594],[16.008203,2.97666],[15.958008,3.028711],[15.928711,3.075781],[15.904883,3.09585],[15.849316,3.103076],[15.775,3.127197],[15.676563,3.229687],[15.580859,3.329297],[15.458398,3.456836],[15.360156,3.567139],[15.239844,3.702148],[15.128711,3.826904],[15.062109,3.947217],[15.034863,4.016357],[15.067383,4.022949],[15.11543,4.024463],[15.13584,4.036914],[15.136914,4.069141],[15.0875,4.163965],[15.063574,4.284863],[15.022754,4.358545],[14.893555,4.471875],[14.77041,4.558105],[14.73125,4.602393],[14.708984,4.665576],[14.661719,5.065527],[14.640625,5.179053],[14.601758,5.228809],[14.573535,5.251709],[14.562988,5.279932],[14.568066,5.351074],[14.584375,5.414746],[14.583594,5.439648],[14.616895,5.495508],[14.616895,5.865137],[14.598828,5.883984],[14.577246,5.916016],[14.54248,5.913574],[14.503125,5.916895],[14.463867,5.970703],[14.431152,6.038721],[14.440723,6.086719],[14.475,6.126807],[14.512109,6.161914],[14.559375,6.191211],[14.699512,6.250244],[14.739258,6.279785],[14.764063,6.316357],[14.780371,6.365723],[14.861914,6.555713],[14.982715,6.745312],[15.03457,6.784424],[15.086328,6.909912],[15.157129,7.063574],[15.18584,7.134912],[15.206738,7.206152],[15.245898,7.263574],[15.379102,7.358154],[15.480078,7.523779],[15.589258,7.515039],[15.70127,7.488428],[15.84502,7.475293],[15.957617,7.507568],[16.030664,7.572119],[16.191113,7.623437],[16.378906,7.683545],[16.404395,7.772363],[16.459375,7.818994],[16.523242,7.859961],[16.545313,7.865479],[16.550195,7.835889],[16.588965,7.743359],[16.668359,7.651758],[16.784766,7.550977],[16.818164,7.557324],[16.890332,7.633691],[17.071973,7.680811],[17.117969,7.701904],[17.246973,7.812988],[17.402148,7.88457],[17.436426,7.890918],[17.492676,7.909814],[17.649414,7.983594],[17.76084,7.973828],[17.940137,7.985449],[18.238867,8.020361],[18.455078,8.032031],[18.56416,8.045898],[18.591602,8.060791],[18.633594,8.167725],[18.666211,8.197705],[18.747461,8.243799],[18.906445,8.405078],[19.01084,8.541211],[19.039844,8.586914],[19.042383,8.590283],[19.063867,8.598828],[19.108691,8.656152],[19.06416,8.71543],[18.886035,8.836035],[18.888574,8.85249],[18.87832,8.873193],[18.888281,8.889746],[18.95625,8.938867],[19.047852,8.99502],[19.145508,9.015967],[19.400293,9.011621],[19.61748,9.023584],[19.668359,9.020898],[19.837695,9.049365],[19.953516,9.075146],[20.072656,9.133203],[20.34209,9.1271],[20.566895,9.274951],[20.631445,9.301367],[20.659668,9.324512],[20.668164,9.347119],[20.773242,9.405664],[20.891016,9.527148],[20.98418,9.636279],[21.009473,9.713232],[21.263867,9.974609],[21.352441,9.969141],[21.395996,10.001367],[21.496875,10.175684],[21.528027,10.207812],[21.575781,10.218555],[21.632715,10.238281],[21.682715,10.289844],[21.725781,10.366553],[21.726172,10.461621],[21.706543,10.537891],[21.706543,10.574805],[21.730664,10.608691],[21.771484,10.642822],[21.964844,10.73667],[22.01377,10.782031],[22.043164,10.822705],[22.097168,10.830078],[22.15625,10.826074],[22.193652,10.851367],[22.235937,10.894141],[22.369824,10.951514],[22.493848,10.99624],[22.624023,10.977344],[22.730176,10.954053],[22.817383,10.927197],[22.860059,10.919678]]]}",Central African Republic
"{""type"":""Polygon"",""coordinates"":[[[0.21748,14.911475],[0.203809,14.865039],[0.202734,14.782813],[0.185059,14.65293],[0.163867,14.497217],[0.250586,14.396436],[0.35459,14.288037],[0.38252,14.245801],[0.354883,14.139014],[0.374023,14.076367],[0.429199,13.972119],[0.522363,13.839746],[0.618164,13.703418],[0.68457,13.6854],[0.747754,13.674512],[0.786035,13.650049],[0.842285,13.626416],[0.897949,13.610938],[0.946582,13.581152],[0.977734,13.551953],[1.017871,13.467871],[1.125977,13.412354],[1.201172,13.35752],[1.170898,13.32959],[1.076855,13.340771],[0.988477,13.364844],[0.976758,13.324512],[0.973047,13.170361],[0.987305,13.041895],[1.00791,13.024805],[1.096777,13.001123],[1.308691,12.834277],[1.500488,12.676465],[1.564941,12.6354],[1.671094,12.619824],[1.789844,12.613281],[1.840918,12.627881],[1.956152,12.707422],[2.017383,12.716211],[2.073828,12.713965],[2.10459,12.70127],[2.159766,12.636426],[2.211523,12.538428],[2.22627,12.466064],[2.221387,12.427246],[2.203809,12.412598],[2.109375,12.393848],[2.068555,12.37915],[2.058398,12.357959],[2.072949,12.309375],[2.091406,12.277979],[2.194434,12.136475],[2.343359,11.945996],[2.38916,11.89707],[2.363281,11.840088],[2.287207,11.69126],[2.230859,11.62915],[1.980371,11.418408],[1.857617,11.443359],[1.6,11.400635],[1.561426,11.449121],[1.501367,11.455566],[1.426758,11.447119],[1.399707,11.428711],[1.391504,11.408008],[1.364844,11.378906],[1.317383,11.295264],[1.280469,11.273975],[1.234668,11.261035],[1.178711,11.262744],[1.145801,11.251904],[1.145508,11.2104],[1.135547,11.174365],[1.097559,11.156348],[1.081543,11.116016],[1.08457,11.076367],[1.062305,11.058203],[1.013867,11.068115],[0.985059,11.079004],[0.958008,11.027783],[0.924609,10.992822],[0.900488,10.993262],[0.642969,10.983057],[0.549121,10.95542],[0.492676,10.95498],[0.490723,10.978174],[0.48418,10.991992],[0.159277,11.069629],[-0.068604,11.115625],[-0.299463,11.166895],[-0.312549,11.118896],[-0.345752,11.087939],[-0.395605,11.085693],[-0.430322,11.093262],[-0.453516,11.056299],[-0.491699,11.007617],[-0.545215,10.983691],[-0.597656,10.953662],[-0.627148,10.927393],[-0.648535,10.926758],[-0.701416,10.988965],[-0.771582,10.995264],[-0.90293,10.984717],[-0.961816,11.001709],[-1.04248,11.010059],[-1.232617,10.997217],[-1.536768,11.022656],[-1.586475,11.008887],[-1.599658,10.997656],[-1.900635,10.994678],[-2.231934,10.991406],[-2.50918,10.988721],[-2.75166,10.986377],[-2.7521,10.996973],[-2.829932,10.998389],[-2.838574,10.97749],[-2.907324,10.727979],[-2.914893,10.592334],[-2.878418,10.507959],[-2.837207,10.454639],[-2.791162,10.432422],[-2.786621,10.401904],[-2.823437,10.362939],[-2.820313,10.322852],[-2.7771,10.281592],[-2.766504,10.238184],[-2.788477,10.192578],[-2.783203,10.083105],[-2.750732,9.909668],[-2.749805,9.797217],[-2.780518,9.74585],[-2.765967,9.658057],[-2.706201,9.533936],[-2.69585,9.481348],[-2.717188,9.457129],[-2.766602,9.424707],[-2.816748,9.42583],[-2.875146,9.500928],[-2.900879,9.534619],[-2.948145,9.610742],[-2.988281,9.687354],[-3.042627,9.720898],[-3.095801,9.7521],[-3.160693,9.84917],[-3.223535,9.895459],[-3.289697,9.882227],[-3.386279,9.900293],[-3.581152,9.924316],[-3.790625,9.917188],[-3.877637,9.894922],[-3.963477,9.859619],[-4.181152,9.781738],[-4.267187,9.743262],[-4.332227,9.645703],[-4.406201,9.647998],[-4.480273,9.679248],[-4.526611,9.723486],[-4.62583,9.713574],[-4.721777,9.756543],[-4.814453,9.841162],[-4.882715,9.868945],[-4.969922,9.930078],[-4.994043,10.046484],[-5.049316,10.12832],[-5.099854,10.241602],[-5.175293,10.292627],[-5.262305,10.319678],[-5.382275,10.314014],[-5.461279,10.35957],[-5.523535,10.426025],[-5.507031,10.483447],[-5.479004,10.565088],[-5.475684,10.643945],[-5.45708,10.771387],[-5.468555,10.931055],[-5.490479,11.042383],[-5.424219,11.088721],[-5.347412,11.130273],[-5.299854,11.205957],[-5.250244,11.375781],[-5.229395,11.522461],[-5.244775,11.576758],[-5.270312,11.619873],[-5.290527,11.683301],[-5.302002,11.760449],[-5.288135,11.82793],[-5.230176,11.890283],[-5.15752,11.942383],[-5.105908,11.967529],[-4.968994,11.993311],[-4.797949,12.032129],[-4.699316,12.076172],[-4.627246,12.120215],[-4.586914,12.155029],[-4.546045,12.226465],[-4.479883,12.281787],[-4.428711,12.337598],[-4.421582,12.493066],[-4.421924,12.581592],[-4.459863,12.630371],[-4.480615,12.672217],[-4.2271,12.793701],[-4.225244,12.879492],[-4.260645,12.975342],[-4.310254,13.05249],[-4.328711,13.119043],[-4.258691,13.197314],[-4.196191,13.256152],[-4.151025,13.306201],[-4.051172,13.382422],[-3.947314,13.402197],[-3.853467,13.373535],[-3.575781,13.194189],[-3.527637,13.182715],[-3.469922,13.196387],[-3.396729,13.243701],[-3.301758,13.280762],[-3.266748,13.400781],[-3.270166,13.577441],[-3.248633,13.65835],[-3.198437,13.672852],[-3.038672,13.639111],[-2.997217,13.637109],[-2.95083,13.648438],[-2.91709,13.679492],[-2.918506,13.736377],[-2.925879,13.786768],[-2.873926,13.950732],[-2.778857,14.07373],[-2.586719,14.227588],[-2.526904,14.258301],[-2.457227,14.274121],[-2.113232,14.168457],[-2.057129,14.194629],[-1.973047,14.456543],[-1.879785,14.481494],[-1.767773,14.486035],[-1.695068,14.508496],[-1.657324,14.526807],[-1.493652,14.626074],[-1.20498,14.761523],[-1.049561,14.819531],[-1.019189,14.841357],[-0.907959,14.937402],[-0.760449,15.047754],[-0.666455,15.069775],[-0.536523,15.077881],[-0.454492,15.059668],[-0.432275,15.028516],[-0.40542,15.0125],[-0.235889,15.059424],[0.007324,14.984814],[0.21748,14.911475]]]}",Burkina Faso
"{""type"":""Polygon"",""coordinates"":[[[27.40332,5.10918],[27.439258,5.039209],[27.491016,4.967578],[27.66416,4.845996],[27.719238,4.77832],[27.761426,4.703223],[27.788086,4.644678],[27.841602,4.597754],[27.916602,4.56792],[27.980664,4.53208],[28.019824,4.479395],[28.078613,4.424805],[28.19209,4.350244],[28.247266,4.348535],[28.311035,4.338037],[28.367188,4.318652],[28.427539,4.32417],[28.524805,4.372852],[28.639551,4.454492],[28.727051,4.50498],[28.939355,4.487061],[29.057422,4.445947],[29.151465,4.388184],[29.224902,4.391895],[29.384863,4.498389],[29.469629,4.611816],[29.552051,4.636035],[29.676855,4.586914],[29.779883,4.480957],[29.870215,4.327148],[29.933984,4.268506],[30.021387,4.177637],[30.194922,3.981934],[30.420703,3.883887],[30.508301,3.835693],[30.536914,3.787207],[30.553516,3.722949],[30.559375,3.652783],[30.586719,3.624219],[30.647656,3.634131],[30.699902,3.644092],[30.757227,3.624219],[30.796973,3.573145],[30.816895,3.53335],[30.838574,3.490723],[30.895313,3.463672],[30.906445,3.408936],[30.867578,3.342139],[30.827832,3.282617],[30.779297,3.163379],[30.754004,3.041797],[30.786523,3.001367],[30.821387,2.967578],[30.839941,2.933496],[30.850781,2.893652],[30.84668,2.847021],[30.769531,2.677979],[30.729883,2.530273],[30.728613,2.455371],[30.830078,2.400439],[30.961914,2.403271],[31.003613,2.369385],[31.045313,2.315527],[31.082129,2.288086],[31.137598,2.288867],[31.176367,2.270068],[31.191406,2.232275],[31.236328,2.191357],[31.274023,2.146289],[31.256055,2.088477],[31.252734,2.04458],[31.158789,1.922021],[30.942578,1.682813],[30.478125,1.239062],[30.477832,1.238818],[30.321094,1.185303],[30.240137,1.102783],[30.18291,0.973486],[30.047363,0.863525],[29.942871,0.819238],[29.931641,0.792871],[29.923828,0.673926],[29.934473,0.499023],[29.885449,0.418945],[29.814648,0.263623],[29.777832,0.166357],[29.749707,0.147217],[29.717676,0.09834],[29.697852,-0.060205],[29.684375,-0.113574],[29.633203,-0.441699],[29.647852,-0.535254],[29.608203,-0.691309],[29.606445,-0.783105],[29.590039,-0.887109],[29.561914,-0.977344],[29.564062,-1.121387],[29.57998,-1.356738],[29.576953,-1.387891],[29.537793,-1.409766],[29.467969,-1.468066],[29.401953,-1.507422],[29.35166,-1.517578],[29.268164,-1.621582],[29.196582,-1.719922],[29.143262,-1.816016],[29.129395,-1.860254],[29.140625,-1.98457],[29.148047,-2.131836],[29.131543,-2.195117],[29.106445,-2.233203],[28.989551,-2.312793],[28.912695,-2.370313],[28.876367,-2.400293],[28.857617,-2.44668],[28.891406,-2.555566],[28.893945,-2.635059],[28.921777,-2.682031],[29.014355,-2.720215],[29.01416,-2.758301],[29.016602,-2.799609],[29.064746,-2.850781],[29.153223,-2.955273],[29.224414,-3.053516],[29.226074,-3.138672],[29.212305,-3.28125],[29.210059,-3.363281],[29.217188,-3.475684],[29.216797,-3.684961],[29.211816,-3.833789],[29.223242,-3.91084],[29.331348,-4.09541],[29.379199,-4.299707],[29.403223,-4.449316],[29.404199,-4.49668],[29.367578,-4.668848],[29.325684,-4.835645],[29.323438,-4.898828],[29.342773,-4.983105],[29.420117,-5.176172],[29.476465,-5.316602],[29.503711,-5.400977],[29.542383,-5.499805],[29.594141,-5.650781],[29.607031,-5.722656],[29.596387,-5.775977],[29.49082,-5.96543],[29.480078,-6.025],[29.50625,-6.17207],[29.54082,-6.313867],[29.590625,-6.394434],[29.709668,-6.616895],[29.798145,-6.691895],[29.961816,-6.803125],[30.10625,-6.915039],[30.161816,-6.973047],[30.212695,-7.037891],[30.313184,-7.203711],[30.374512,-7.338672],[30.406738,-7.460645],[30.485645,-7.627148],[30.558887,-7.781934],[30.653809,-7.970898],[30.720898,-8.104395],[30.751172,-8.193652],[30.57793,-8.22002],[30.327539,-8.258203],[30.051367,-8.300293],[29.766211,-8.34375],[29.483789,-8.386914],[29.215625,-8.427832],[28.972266,-8.464941],[28.898145,-8.485449],[28.934473,-8.590234],[28.917773,-8.700586],[28.869531,-8.78584],[28.793555,-8.891016],[28.758789,-8.932617],[28.68125,-9.014648],[28.616504,-9.072266],[28.484277,-9.169434],[28.400684,-9.224805],[28.400195,-9.275],[28.540527,-9.510059],[28.604199,-9.678809],[28.630078,-9.83125],[28.628906,-9.91875],[28.623535,-10.098828],[28.617188,-10.312988],[28.607422,-10.397363],[28.645508,-10.550195],[28.638867,-10.669238],[28.544238,-10.802344],[28.517969,-10.933203],[28.470312,-11.10957],[28.404199,-11.354395],[28.357227,-11.483008],[28.383398,-11.566699],[28.407031,-11.622852],[28.431836,-11.69834],[28.48252,-11.812109],[28.541602,-11.879199],[28.574609,-11.908105],[28.769434,-12.05127],[28.85,-12.120508],[28.973438,-12.257813],[29.064355,-12.348828],[29.191211,-12.370215],[29.34375,-12.404785],[29.427539,-12.43125],[29.485547,-12.418457],[29.504883,-12.386133],[29.502246,-12.317578],[29.491992,-12.266895],[29.508203,-12.228223],[29.559766,-12.202441],[29.691992,-12.19834],[29.749609,-12.164063],[29.795117,-12.155469],[29.795313,-12.306152],[29.795508,-12.450586],[29.795605,-12.625879],[29.795801,-12.827051],[29.796094,-12.99209],[29.796289,-13.16748],[29.796484,-13.369727],[29.795313,-13.392773],[29.775195,-13.438086],[29.722656,-13.453809],[29.651758,-13.414355],[29.647656,-13.372949],[29.630273,-13.298535],[29.597168,-13.260547],[29.554199,-13.248926],[29.481445,-13.267969],[29.381836,-13.322852],[29.253711,-13.370801],[29.201855,-13.39834],[29.111621,-13.395117],[29.014258,-13.368848],[28.942285,-13.307129],[28.92168,-13.214648],[28.858789,-13.119434],[28.773145,-12.981934],[28.730078,-12.925488],[28.672949,-12.861328],[28.61543,-12.854102],[28.550879,-12.836133],[28.51123,-12.742188],[28.474414,-12.62334],[28.451465,-12.577441],[28.412891,-12.518066],[28.357715,-12.482031],[28.237305,-12.43457],[28.068848,-12.368164],[27.857422,-12.284863],[27.756836,-12.280859],[27.644336,-12.266797],[27.573828,-12.227051],[27.533398,-12.195313],[27.487012,-12.079688],[27.423633,-11.944531],[27.238086,-11.783496],[27.196387,-11.605078],[27.15918,-11.579199],[27.09541,-11.59375],[27.046094,-11.615918],[27.02666,-11.66377],[26.976855,-11.824609],[26.949609,-11.898828],[26.930859,-11.919336],[26.89043,-11.943555],[26.824023,-11.965234],[26.729688,-11.975977],[26.596387,-11.97207],[26.429688,-11.947852],[26.339648,-11.929883],[26.096387,-11.903223],[26.025977,-11.890137],[25.926563,-11.855273],[25.854883,-11.820117],[25.618848,-11.744141],[25.511914,-11.753418],[25.459961,-11.699805],[25.413379,-11.673535],[25.349414,-11.623047],[25.320703,-11.553516],[25.282617,-11.40498],[25.291797,-11.325488],[25.319336,-11.236914],[25.28877,-11.212402],[25.245996,-11.212402],[25.184863,-11.242969],[25.075977,-11.260059],[24.876855,-11.299121],[24.806348,-11.321191],[24.728125,-11.337793],[24.668262,-11.35293],[24.518555,-11.438477],[24.466602,-11.447656],[24.37793,-11.41709],[24.335156,-11.371289],[24.37793,-11.319336],[24.396289,-11.255176],[24.365723,-11.129883],[24.319922,-11.071777],[24.187207,-11.02998],[24.136523,-11.025977],[24.115137,-10.955664],[24.078418,-10.891504],[24.002734,-10.879102],[23.966504,-10.871777],[23.928711,-10.891504],[23.907324,-10.943457],[23.901172,-10.983203],[23.833887,-11.013672],[23.696387,-11.007617],[23.559961,-10.978613],[23.463965,-10.969336],[23.400195,-10.976465],[23.156738,-11.074805],[23.07627,-11.087891],[22.814746,-11.080273],[22.666504,-11.059766],[22.561035,-11.055859],[22.486133,-11.086719],[22.392969,-11.159473],[22.314941,-11.198633],[22.278809,-11.194141],[22.256641,-11.163672],[22.226172,-11.121973],[22.216699,-11.012695],[22.17793,-10.892285],[22.203516,-10.829492],[22.280469,-10.783984],[22.307031,-10.691309],[22.283203,-10.551562],[22.281641,-10.45332],[22.302441,-10.39668],[22.274512,-10.259082],[22.197754,-10.040625],[22.08916,-9.862793],[21.948633,-9.725586],[21.856641,-9.594238],[21.813184,-9.46875],[21.829492,-9.168457],[21.871875,-8.903516],[21.905371,-8.693359],[21.895898,-8.341113],[21.800879,-8.111914],[21.780078,-7.86543],[21.833594,-7.60166],[21.841602,-7.420996],[21.806055,-7.328613],[21.781641,-7.314648],[21.751074,-7.305469],[21.51084,-7.29668],[21.190332,-7.284961],[20.910938,-7.281445],[20.607813,-7.277734],[20.558398,-7.244434],[20.53584,-7.182813],[20.536914,-7.121777],[20.59873,-6.935156],[20.590039,-6.919922],[20.482227,-6.91582],[20.190039,-6.946289],[19.997461,-6.976465],[19.875195,-6.986328],[19.660352,-7.037109],[19.527637,-7.144434],[19.483789,-7.279492],[19.487402,-7.390723],[19.479883,-7.472168],[19.419336,-7.557324],[19.37168,-7.655078],[19.369922,-7.706543],[19.34082,-7.966602],[19.142676,-8.001465],[18.944434,-8.001465],[18.89834,-7.998145],[18.653418,-7.936035],[18.562695,-7.935937],[18.484668,-7.968555],[18.334863,-8.000293],[18.191504,-8.023828],[18.047168,-8.100781],[18.008789,-8.107617],[17.913086,-8.067676],[17.778809,-8.071387],[17.643359,-8.090723],[17.57959,-8.099023],[17.536035,-8.075879],[17.411328,-7.881934],[17.24502,-7.62334],[17.155078,-7.461328],[17.121582,-7.419043],[17.06377,-7.363086],[16.984766,-7.257422],[16.952051,-7.157031],[16.96582,-7.062109],[16.919434,-6.933984],[16.813086,-6.772559],[16.742969,-6.618457],[16.709375,-6.47168],[16.700977,-6.345996],[16.717773,-6.241406],[16.697266,-6.164258],[16.639551,-6.114551],[16.608008,-6.051563],[16.585156,-6.025293],[16.537109,-5.96582],[16.431445,-5.900195],[16.315234,-5.865625],[16.060156,-5.864941],[15.726953,-5.863867],[15.425,-5.868848],[15.089355,-5.874512],[14.749414,-5.880078],[14.65791,-5.888867],[14.398633,-5.892676],[14.19082,-5.875977],[14.11377,-5.865137],[13.978516,-5.857227],[13.764551,-5.855176],[13.649023,-5.861719],[13.371484,-5.861816],[13.346484,-5.863379],[13.302637,-5.881836],[13.184375,-5.85625],[13.068164,-5.864844],[13.00332,-5.836133],[12.86084,-5.854102],[12.791602,-5.877734],[12.680664,-5.96084],[12.514551,-6.004199],[12.45293,-6.000488],[12.411719,-5.986328],[12.315039,-5.895313],[12.24043,-5.807324],[12.213672,-5.758691],[12.255273,-5.746484],[12.386035,-5.727734],[12.48457,-5.71875],[12.503711,-5.695801],[12.518945,-5.424609],[12.522363,-5.148926],[12.487402,-5.112695],[12.453223,-5.090625],[12.451465,-5.071484],[12.502734,-5.036914],[12.573535,-4.996582],[12.596191,-4.978418],[12.674805,-4.905371],[12.829688,-4.736621],[12.947461,-4.695313],[13.057324,-4.651074],[13.072754,-4.634766],[13.087402,-4.601953],[13.136621,-4.604297],[13.152344,-4.620313],[13.176465,-4.655859],[13.219629,-4.705859],[13.297266,-4.765234],[13.375781,-4.829395],[13.414941,-4.837402],[13.478418,-4.80498],[13.55166,-4.756738],[13.65957,-4.721484],[13.685352,-4.688672],[13.699414,-4.618359],[13.707617,-4.543262],[13.71709,-4.454492],[13.739063,-4.44248],[13.778027,-4.433887],[13.849512,-4.458887],[13.882324,-4.484668],[13.940918,-4.484668],[13.978418,-4.46123],[14.046875,-4.41748],[14.133887,-4.4],[14.227051,-4.358105],[14.316211,-4.304102],[14.358301,-4.299414],[14.40293,-4.369727],[14.442773,-4.419043],[14.449805,-4.449512],[14.409961,-4.508105],[14.36543,-4.585547],[14.40293,-4.681641],[14.411914,-4.775],[14.410742,-4.83125],[14.440918,-4.854102],[14.461621,-4.864941],[14.493945,-4.85166],[14.557617,-4.855762],[14.633984,-4.885059],[14.70791,-4.881738],[14.779297,-4.845703],[14.912109,-4.705566],[15.10625,-4.461035],[15.267188,-4.307617],[15.394629,-4.244922],[15.480957,-4.171777],[15.525977,-4.087988],[15.600098,-4.030957],[15.75459,-3.985547],[15.872461,-3.934277],[15.990039,-3.766211],[16.146777,-3.46416],[16.190625,-3.194434],[16.217383,-3.030273],[16.201855,-2.464746],[16.191602,-2.279102],[16.215332,-2.177832],[16.273926,-2.108203],[16.433594,-1.96084],[16.540723,-1.840137],[16.622461,-1.698926],[16.780078,-1.376367],[16.849121,-1.272461],[16.879883,-1.225879],[16.974707,-1.139941],[17.107617,-1.064453],[17.278809,-0.999609],[17.542871,-0.775],[17.752832,-0.549023],[17.724121,-0.277539],[17.773145,-0.052393],[17.887695,0.234131],[17.925195,0.537305],[17.885742,0.856885],[17.902441,1.118066],[18.011719,1.422119],[18.057813,1.534863],[18.072852,1.719385],[18.072168,2.013281],[18.211621,2.414941],[18.343457,2.65542],[18.490918,2.924414],[18.54707,3.087012],[18.622168,3.304053],[18.610352,3.478418],[18.59668,3.678711],[18.633691,3.954297],[18.619922,4.116602],[18.56748,4.257568],[18.594141,4.34624],[18.699902,4.382617],[18.831738,4.523438],[19.068555,4.891406],[19.323438,5.070752],[19.500977,5.12749],[19.686035,5.121387],[19.806543,5.089307],[19.8625,5.031299],[20.002344,4.944727],[20.226367,4.829639],[20.393555,4.686182],[20.486523,4.541553],[20.558105,4.462695],[20.647461,4.435645],[20.792969,4.447314],[20.955762,4.413135],[21.125586,4.332178],[21.229785,4.302197],[21.268359,4.323096],[21.350195,4.311377],[21.537598,4.244824],[21.687012,4.281396],[21.908203,4.253906],[22.422168,4.134961],[22.449707,4.155127],[22.461816,4.159766],[22.505664,4.207666],[22.617188,4.445557],[22.711719,4.591748],[22.755762,4.64668],[22.864551,4.723877],[22.992871,4.743848],[23.115918,4.736914],[23.218848,4.702979],[23.312891,4.663525],[23.417188,4.663135],[23.523633,4.70127],[23.681836,4.770801],[23.848438,4.816357],[23.991699,4.86626],[24.227734,4.953857],[24.319824,4.994141],[24.437109,5.009961],[24.765527,4.930078],[24.978418,4.982959],[25.065234,4.967432],[25.249316,5.024561],[25.283105,5.062695],[25.400195,5.255908],[25.525098,5.312109],[25.713867,5.283691],[25.819922,5.253711],[26.173535,5.171143],[26.632617,5.085205],[26.767578,5.071924],[26.82207,5.062402],[26.870117,5.075684],[27.020605,5.184375],[27.071875,5.199756],[27.114941,5.197852],[27.40332,5.10918]]]}",Democratic Republic of the Congo
```

I first tried to read it into geojson
`geodf = gpd.read_file('myfilepath')`

But I get this message about recursion:

```
... last 5 frames repeated, from the frame below ...

~/Desktop/tiuk/side_projects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    104             try:
    105                 if (
--> 106                     hasattr(self["geometry"].values, "crs")
    107                     and self["geometry"].values.crs
    108                     and crs

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

So I tried using pandas:

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfilepath')
df

    geometry                                            Name
0   {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[22.860059,1...   Central African Republic
1   {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[0.21748,14....   Burkina Faso
2   {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[27.40332,5....   Democratic Republic of the Congo
```

Which at least reads the content in a df, but I do not understand how to get from this df to the above format. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with:

```
df = geopandas.read_file('geo.csv',
                         GEOM_POSSIBLE_NAMES="geometry",
                         KEEP_GEOM_COLUMNS="NO")
df
```

Output:

```
                               Name                                           geometry
0          Central African Republic  POLYGON ((22.86006 10.91968, 22.93076 10.79531...
1                      Burkina Faso  POLYGON ((0.21748 14.91147, 0.20381 14.86504, ...
2  Democratic Republic of the Congo  POLYGON ((27.40332 5.10918, 27.43926 5.03921, ...
```

P.S. This [geopandas issue](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1234) explains the problem in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with perl's answer. What you have essentially is the geometry details in the coordinate column. If simply read using pandas, you can transform it to geodataframe using following code

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import wkt    
geo_df= pd.read_csv(data_dir.joinpath("filename.csv"), low_memory=False)
geo_df['geometry'] = geo_df['coordinates'].apply(wkt.loads)
```

This would read the coordinates and covert them into geometry object.